# How to change iOS Notification Center pulling direction?

Tags: iphone, ios, rotation

I have set the root viewer's direction to upside down.
When I enter the app, I can pull out the notification center from the top (near the home button).
But after I pressed home button, then went back to my app, the notification center was pulled out from the bottom, just like the view's direction was not changed.

I'm wondering how to change iOS Notification Center pulling direction?

I'm using Xcode 4.6 and testing on iPhone 5 6.02

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The UI for notifications is stupid, I agree. It should be a two-finger swipe from the top (or right) edge to get it (like in Mountain Lion with a track-pad). However, it's a system-owned gesture so you can't really get rid of it, and even if you find a workaround there's no guarantee it will keep working on different OS releases. I'm not sure, but Apple may even reject your app if you try to alter system behaviour.

Comment: You may not like this answer - but I think it's probably best that you don't try to subvert system-owned gestures. Instead re-design your app UI to not interfere with them. I know it's annoying, but blame Apple, not me!